# Value of type xxx has no member xxx Error in SwiftuI?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swiftui

I've been struggling with this for ages and I can't figure out why I can't pass this at all.

I have an array that look like this:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "tickets": {
        "open_tickets": [
            {
                "uuid": "XXXXXXX",
                "package": {
                    "title": "XXXX",
                    "buyer": {
                        "name": "XXX",
                        "family_name": null,
                        "email": "XXXXX",
                        "buyer_profile": {
                            "telephone": "5435345"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "closed_tickets": []
    }
}
```

I'm trying access the nested array(s). specifically, `open_tickets`.

So, I've tried this:

I've placed this in at the top of my view between the struct and body:

```
@ObservedObject var fetcherL = FetcherL()
```

And this is now I try to read that data from a remote URL:

```
public class FetcherL: ObservableObject {

    @Published var ticket = [Open_Tickets]()
    
    init(){
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {

let url = URL(string: "HTTPS://xxxxxxx")
var request = URLRequest(url: url!)


        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data,response,error) in
            do {
                if let d = data {
                    
                    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(RootO.self, from: d)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        //self.ticket = res.tickets.open_tickets
                        self.ticket = res.tickets.open_tickets
                        
                    }
                    
              
                }else {
                    print("No Data")
                }
            } catch {
                print (error)
            }
            
        }.resume()

    }

}


struct RootO: Codable {

    let tickets: [Tickets]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case tickets = "tickets"
    }
}


struct Tickets: Codable {
    
    let open_tickets: [Open_Tickets]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case open_tickets = "open_tickets"

        }
}


struct Open_Tickets: Codable{
    
    let ticket_number: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
           case ticket_number = "ticket_number"

        }
    
}
```

But this code Is giving this error and stops me from compiling my app:

```
Value of type '[Tickets]' has no member 'open_tickets'
```

[image]

Can someone please advice on this?

Comment: change ```let tickets: [Tickets]``` to ```let tickets: Tickets``` from the model. In json ```tickets``` is not an array it's an object.

Comment: @RajaKishan, that produces `keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "tickets", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"tickets\", intValue: nil) (\"tickets\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: use some site to create model from json: https://app.quicktype.io

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the error is in your **Root0**:

```
struct RootO: Codable {

    let tickets: [Tickets]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case tickets = "tickets"
    }
}
```

You are expecting your Root0 to have a field called **tickets** expecting an array of **Tickets**, but the **tickets** attribute of the response is a dictionary of `[String: [Tickets]`

Here is a working solution:

```
let json = """
{
    "status": "OK",
    "tickets": {
        "open_tickets": [
            {
                "uuid": "XXXXXXX",
                "package": {
                    "title": "XXXX",
                    "buyer": {
                        "name": "XXX",
                        "family_name": null,
                        "email": "XXXXX",
                        "buyer_profile": {
                            "telephone": "5435345"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "closed_tickets": []
    }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!


struct RootO: Codable {
    let tickets: [String: [Ticket]]

    var openTickets: [Ticket] {
        if let data = tickets["open_tickets"] {
            return data
        } else {
            return []
        }
    }

    var closedTickets: [Ticket] {
        if let data = tickets["closed_tickets"] {
            return data
        } else {
            return []
        }
    }
}


struct Ticket: Codable {
    let ticketNumber: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ticketNumber = "uuid"
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let decoded = try! decoder.decode(RootO.self, from: json)

print("Open tickets = \(decoded.openTickets.count)")
print("Closed tickets = \(decoded.closedTickets.count)")
```

### Some advice:

- Use *singular* nouns for your struct **Ticket** not Tickets.
- You do not need to provide the coding keys if the attribute name is identical

Answer (score 0):

Change RootO structure and try it, "tickets" is object not an array

```
struct RootO: Codable {
    
        let tickets: Tickets
        
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    
            case tickets = "tickets"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes tickets is an object and not an array, but it is not an object of type Tickets - hence you are not providing a correct answer.